# GAN - RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

In order to build a `GAN` architecture I am using this kind of `Generator`:

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, nz=128, num_classes=120, channels=3, nfilt=64):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.nz = nz
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.channels = channels
        
        self.label_emb = nn.Embedding(num_classes, nz)
        self.pixelnorm = PixelwiseNorm()
        self.upconv1 = UpConvBlock(2*nz, nfilt*16, num_classes, k_size=4, stride=1, padding=0, norm="cbn", dropout_p=0.15)
        self.upconv2 = UpConvBlock(nfilt*16, nfilt*8, num_classes, k_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, norm="cbn", dropout_p=0.10)
        self.upconv3 = UpConvBlock(nfilt*8, nfilt*4, num_classes, k_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, norm="cbn", dropout_p=0.05)
        self.upconv4 = UpConvBlock(nfilt*4, nfilt*2, num_classes, k_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, norm="cbn", dropout_p=0.05)
        self.upconv5 = UpConvBlock(nfilt*2, nfilt, num_classes, k_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, norm="cbn", dropout_p=0.05)
        self.self_attn = Self_Attn(nfilt)
        self.upconv6 = UpConvBlock(nfilt, 3, num_classes, k_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, norm="cbn")
        self.out_conv = spectral_norm(nn.Conv2d(3, 3, 3, 1, 1, bias=False))  
        self.out_activ = nn.Tanh()
        
    def forward(self, inputs):
        z, labels = inputs
        
        enc = self.label_emb(labels).view((-1, self.nz, 1, 1))
        enc = F.normalize(enc, p=2, dim=1)
        x = torch.cat((z, enc), 1)
        
        x = self.upconv1((x, labels))
        x = self.upconv2((x, labels))
        x = self.upconv3((x, labels))
        x = self.upconv4((x, labels))
        x = self.upconv5((x, labels))
        x = self.self_attn(x)
        x = self.upconv6((x, labels))
        x = self.out_conv(x)
        img = self.out_activ(x)           
        return img
```

Which is valorized: `netG = Generator(nz, num_classes=len(encoded_labels), nfilt=64).to(device)`

When I start the training part I get this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:21: UserWarning: To copy construct from a tensor, it is recommended to use sourceTensor.clone().detach() or sourceTensor.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True), rather than torch.tensor(sourceTensor).
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-1a0c4f899e6b> in <module>
     41         errG = (torch.mean((outputR - torch.mean(outputF) + real_labels) ** 2) +
     42                 torch.mean((outputF - torch.mean(outputR) - real_labels) ** 2))/2
---> 43         errG.backward()
     44         optimizerG.step()
     45 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    173     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
    174         tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
--> 175         allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
    176 
    177 def grad(

RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [1, 513, 4, 4]] is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).
```

I have quite clear the meaning of this type of error, but I would like to know what in the code above triggers it